# problem opening what3words app from a webpage link

Tags: android, ios, href

How do you open the what 3 words app on a device from a webpage, Ive tried href="w3w://show?threewords=my.three.words"  and href="w3w://package=com.what3words.android;show?threewords=my.three.words" but nothing seems to happens what is the correct format for this.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your question — you are using the correct format, this seems to be caused by a bug on our side. It's now raised with our tech team,the bug fix will be released in the next couple of weeks. Thanks again for letting us know!

Comment: looks like the comment